# D3 selecting multiple elements in an svg object

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, charts

I've got a bar chart and I'm putting in some labels (after already having created the bars) like this:

```
svg.selectAll("text").data(labels).enter().append("text").text(function(d) { return d; })
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("x", parseFloat(d3.selectAll("#bar").attr("x")) + 
           parseFloat(d3.selectAll("#bar").attr("width"))/2)
.attr("y", 90);

};
//when I am creating the bars using selectAll("rect").... at the end of the attr()
//function I have specified an id called bar so I can reference it later that way.
```

But this only selects the first bar and puts all labels on top of each other. Why is that and how can I select all the rectangles in the svg?

Comment: Can you please provide JS code for drawing your bar chart as well as the text you want to add as label to each column? ( if I understood it correctly )

Answer (score 0):

`#bar` is an [id selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors) and every id must be unique within a document or your file isn't valid.

If you want to have multiple elements called bar you could give them a class of bar and then use a [class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html) instead.

If you want to select all `<rect>` elements then you could use a [type selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#type-selectors).

Comment: so once I've given them a class how can I call .attr on them to get the x and width value of the rectangles?